# Sqlite3, created View from more than 3 tables with WHERE Clause doesn't return results in android?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have created a view in sqlite3+ android using this code;

```
CREATE  VIEW IF NOT EXISTS viewProductList AS
  SELECT p.product_id,c.category_name,s.subcategory_name,pt.type_size
  FROM tCategory c,tproduct p,tproducttype pt,tsubcategory s WHERE (p.cat_id =c._id)
  AND (p.product_type_id=pt.producttype_id)AND(pt.subcategory_id=s.sub_id)GROUP
  BY p.product_id
```

but on querying the View in android using this:

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM viewProductList ", null);
```

it doesnt return results?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try your statement for the view directly? Does it return any values?
Are you sure, that the view is created?

Is it possibly a problem that the statement for your view does not have parentheses?
I would write it like this:

```
CREATE  VIEW IF NOT EXISTS viewProductList AS (
SELECT p.product_id,c.category_name,s.subcategory_name,pt.type_size
FROM tCategory c,tproduct p,tproducttype pt,tsubcategory s WHERE (p.cat_id =c._id)
AND (p.product_type_id=pt.producttype_id)AND(pt.subcategory_id=s.sub_id)GROUP
BY p.product_id)
```